# Put and round function in SAS

Tags: sas

How can I avoid double rounding when using the `round` function and `put` function in SAS together? Take the following code for example:

```
data _null_;
  sd = 11.863499608;
  sdc = strip(put(round(sd,0.0001),10.3));
  put sdc=; 
run;
```

The actual result should be `11.863` but the `put` function rounds up from the already rounded value of `11.8635` to give a final result of `11.864`.
Could someone please tell me how to avoid the second round up by the `put` function? Please note that the first `round` function is extremely important and can't be avoided.

Comment: Did you try changing the format from 10.3 to 10.4?

Comment: Yes, I did and that works but I want 3 decimal places.

Comment: If you only want 3 places, why is the first round important? Is there some other goal here that you're not mentioning? Just round once.

Comment: If you're very familiar with these issues you'll know that the PUT function doesn't always round correctly. It is actually not supposed to be a round function but format applying one. I've encountered so many issues in the past that necessitates first rounding before formatting.

Comment: So then round to 0.001 instead of 0.0001. When round digit by digit 0.4444444449 can become 1 which not seems right.

Comment: You’re “double-rounding”. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding   I haven’t seen PUT function give unexpected results, do you have an example?

Comment: What would be the problem if you rounded to the nearest 0.001 instead of 0.0001 before applying `put`?

Comment: So why not just keep two variables?  `sd4=round(sd,1e-4);sd3c=put(sd,10.3-L);`

Comment: @Quentin, I have been working in the pharma for some years now and I've seen a lot of these issues. To avoid them I have developed the habit of rounding first before using format. And honestly, it has never failed until this one occurred.

Comment: @Lee I wrote a macro to do this automatically for a huge dataset for different parameters. Of all only one had this issue. I used a temporary solution already but was wondering if someone already encountered this issue and has some suggestions.

Comment: @KH_ But you're not doing it right.  Use the same precision for both.

Comment: @KH_ the first line from the Wikipedia article explains why double-rounding using different levels of precision is a problem: "Rounding a number twice in succession to different levels of precision, with the latter precision being coarser, is not guaranteed to give the same result as rounding once to the final precision except in the case of directed rounding. For instance rounding 9.46 to one decimal gives 9.5, and then 10 when rounding to integer using rounding half to even, but would give 9 when rounded to integer directly."

Comment: @Quentin, I do see your point.  Although I did tried `put(round(sd,0.001),10.3)` and it worked for this specific example but messed up the ones that were already rounded properly. All the same, thanks for the insight. I think I will need to go back and look into the whole thing again to see where it's going wrong. I am grateful for all the suggestions and corrections offered on this feed.

Answer (score 1):

There are situations where Fw.d format does not round as expected.  It is best to round to desired number and decimals before using the format.

```
20   data _null_;
21      x=0-1e-5;
22      put x=best.;
23      y = put(x,5.2);
24      put y= 'Negative 0 need to round';
25      z = put(round(x,.01),5.2);
26      put z=;
27      run;

x=-0.00001
y=-0.00 Negative 0 need to round
z=0.00
```

Comment: I've seen that -0 before.  Any other surprises?  I ran a quick simulation, and -0 was the only difference I saw. `data want ; call streaminit(123); do i=1 to 1e6; x=rand("normal") ; y=put(x,5.2) ; z=put(round(x,.01),5.2) ; if y ne z then output ; end ; run ;  `

Comment: I've seen the results that the OP is complaining about, but only with summary statistics.  I "always" round and then put.

Comment: But in that situation -0 is more correct than 0 also 1e-5 should be +0 and only for real zero there should be ±0. But on the hand when you have to round anyway use fixed point math instead. So don't calculate in $ use Cent instead. Don'tu se kg when use g instead. The problem is that summing up thousend times 0.001 you will not get 1. Now substracting 1 from the sum will left you with the tiny fraction that appears because 0.001 can not expressed in floating point format.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
sdc = strip(put(round(sd,0.001),10.3));
```